# How to query from list SQL

Tags: sql, list, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am running the line

```
LIST @my_stage;
```

to get a list of all of the files that have been staged. Is there a way that I can get the most recent file that has been staged? The output shows the files in ascending date order so I would like to grab the last file in this list. Is there a way I can do this? (or something similar)

Answer (score 1):

Just use RESULT_SCAN to process the resultset of the list command
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html

Answer (score 0):

Nick is correct but sometimes working examples help:

```
list @CITIBIKE_TRIPS;
```

[image]

```
select count(*) as file_count
from table(result_scan(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
```

| FILE_COUNT |
| --- |
| 4,227 |

now to be honest, I was fiddling around trying to sum the file size etc etc, so swapped to this code

```
list @CITIBIKE_TRIPS;

set id = (select LAST_QUERY_ID());

select *
from table(result_scan($id));

select count(*) as file_count
from table(result_scan($id));
```

while playing so I could keep referring to the same query..